# Trying to add a third monitor

Tags: graphics

I am trying to connect the third monitor to my Asus P5g41c-m Motherboard, while my other 2 monitors are on my DVI 2x ATI graphics card. I just can't find out how to change the settings within windows or the Bios whith the IGD PCI PEG settings.

The third monitor im trying to connect has VGA HDMI and a DVI port. My motherboard has a VGA and HDMI.

Any ideas?

SPECS:
ASUS P5G41C-M
Core 2 Quad Q8200
MSI Radeon HD4850 (2x DVI)
2x 2GB Samsung 1333MHz RAM

Comment: So you're trying to enable the on-board graphics as well as using an external graphics card? Read your motherboard manufacturer information as this may not be possible. Most systems can't do this as when you plug an external card in it automatically disables the on board graphics adapter.

Comment: What's your processor?

Comment: Intel Core 2 Quad Q8200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its LGA 775 IIRC. In *general* systems that old have a 'seperate' igpu on their chipset (as opposed to newer core based systems that have a on die integrated gpu), and that's connected over PCI, shared with your PCI x16 slot.

That is to say, on a system of that vintage, you can't use your motherboard graphics and discrete gpu at the same time. You'll want a sandy bridge or newer system with the right chipset (a SB era H series chipset wouldn't allow this IIRC) for this to work.

Comment: So I could buy an external USB GPU? Or something like that? No other way to enable a third screen or any software?, What if I add a diffrent PCI or AGP graphics card?

Comment: USB GPUs supposedly suck - its probably going to be horrid unless you're doing basic stuff like spreadsheets and office docs.. Adding a second video card *may* work, but *some* oses don't like graphics cards of different brands. Besides, if you're buying a GPU, might as well get something that supports 3 outputs to start with to simplify things. I can't really give any first hand advice there

Comment: But if my old motherboard doesn't support this, why is there the option in the BIOS settings on NorthBridge?

Comment: Beats me. This is from what I know of working on a system of that era - I had some issues with the discrete gpu, and ended up needing to yank it to get the integrated GPU working.